# Clarification on tribonacci numbers exercise

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, fibonacci-numbers

From what I know the Tribonacci sequence is given by:

T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + T(n-3)

My book says that "We can show by induction that for large enough n, the Fibonacci numbers  satisfy the inequality (1.6)n < F(n) < (1.7)n."

Which of these four functions is the largest that is eventually smaller than T(n)?

Select one:

a. $(1.9)^n$

b. $2^n$

c. $(1.7)^n$

d. $(1.8)^n$

I am not looking for the answer but for way to approach this. I am confused by what is actually asking.

Comment: are those meant to be exponents?

Comment: yes. Sorry I fixed that.

Comment: Actual condition for ${x^n \over T(n)} \to 0$ is $x^3-x^2-x-1 < 0$ (which gives answer (d)), but I don't know how you're supposed to get right result from Fibonacci sequence analysis.

Comment: The limiting ratio for the "Tribonacci" sequence will be $\approx 1.84$, the solution of greatest magnitude to the equation $x^3 - x^2 - x - 1 < 0$

Answer (score 1):

I can show the powers of $2$ grow faster than $T(n)$.
If I start off $T(n-3)=2^{n-3},T(n-2)=2^{n-2},T(n-1)=2^{n-1}$ then 
$$T(n)=T(n-1)+T(n-2)+T(n-3)=\frac{2^n}2+\frac{2^n}4+\frac{2^n}8=\frac782^n$$
So $T(n)$ has started to lag behind powers of $2$.
On the other hand, if I start them off $T(n-1)=1.5^{n-1}$, and so on, I find that $$T(n)=\frac{1.5^n}{1.5}+\frac{1.5^n}{1.5^2}+\frac{1.5^n}{1.5^3}>1.5^n$$ 
so $T(n)$ has started to leap ahead of $1.5^n$